# Trigger for inserting a unique username into a table

Tags: sql

i have a customer table with fields
`CustomerID(PK)`,`FName`,`LName`,`Address`,`Phone`,`DoB`,`username`,`password`

so i need a trigger to be called whenever a new user uses and already existing `username`

Eg:If the table has details for a customer whose username is qwerty and another new user enters qwerty as his username then a trigger should be called

Comment: (1) Please add a tag for the relevant database (+version) (2) Why not handle it in the application?

Comment: As my old friend @DuduMarkovitz states, the specific DBMS needs to be provided to properly address your question. Also, you need to tell us what needs to happen when such collision is encounter.